# simple mysql query with join

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to build a query with 2 tables, categories and products:

Categories

```
catid
parentid
categoryname
description

catid   parentid categoryname
=============================
39      0       MyCatName1
=============================
43      39      MyCatName2
=============================
40      0       MyCatName3
=============================
41      0       MyCatName4
=============================
42      39      MyCatName5
```

Products

```
productid   
catid   
productname     
shortdescription    
description
```

I would like to get all the products from the `products` table where parent `id` is 39, but as you can see, I have no parent `catid` in the table `products`. I should get the category name as well. How can I build the query?

Comment: please show us the query you tried and where it failed. If you want us to do it for you, tag it "work-for-me-for-free" ;-)

Comment: Hi..sorry for ommiting that...i was trying with:SELECT p.* FROM
products p
LEFT INNER JOIN products_categories c ON (p.catid = c.catid AND c.parentid = 39)

Comment: @user2417624: add that to your question and you may get some of your down-votes reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `JOIN` onto the categories table:

```
SELECT p.* FROM
products p
INNER JOIN categories c ON (p.catid = c.catid AND c.parentid = 39)
```

Comment: Hi Jim, your query work great, do you know how can i get the category name as well?

Comment: @user2417624 You can select any categories fields by using c.columnname. I.e. you can change the first line to: `SELECT p.*,c.categoryname`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select P.productid
from Products P join Categories C
  ON P.catid=C.catid
where C.parentid = 39
```